# Windows Explorer Recent Folders

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

I have Windows Explorer pinned to the task bar (I'm on Win-7)

If I right click on the little icon on the task bar, a list pops up of recent folders; cool.

I can then left click on one of those, and explorer opens that folder again; cool.

Alternatively, I can right click on it, and I can remove that item from the list; also cool.

At that point (i.e., after removing an item) the list below it scrolls up and fills the little pane; not cool.

I tried removing item after item and the list seems to be eternally populated; turbo uncool.

Is there a way to empty that entire list, and just populate it with the 3 or 4 folders I want to hit most often ?

Comment: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/clear-taskbar-icons-jump-list-history-windows-7

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Put up an answer with this in it and I'll click on it

Comment: No time right now to create a decent "answer". If you, or someone else wants to create a proper answer with the informaiton provided there, more power to them - I'll even throw an upvote. :)